# How can I delete Live Agent deployments in salesforce?

Tags: liveagent

It's strange, why cannot we delete Live Agent deployments? Have I missed something or is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely not possible to delete deployments through the UI, but you can try deploying a destructive change on the metadata.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Propagating_Destructive_Changes

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to delete Live Agent Deployments at this time. As evidence, I got this error while trying to delete a chat button deployment with version 40.0 of the API:

> Error: delete() not supported for LiveChatDeployment

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/75414)

Comment: The answer I provided is better than the answer that is selected because you cannot do what it suggests.

Comment: Even with the newest version of the API v45, I also get the same error message @JohnLewis mentioned. It appears this is not supported through the API nor through the UI.